# How to link to Google Directions public transit page for specific arrival time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to be able to link to a google directions map from a departure location to an arrival location for a specific future arrival time. So I want to link to a page like this:

https://goo.gl/maps/2n6FC

It's easy to get the directions using the Google Directions API, which is well documented and would return me the stepped directions in a format like json... but the thing is, in my case, linking to Google would be fine, so why try to re-create it, and why would Google want me to do that instead of link?! But the parameters for the links are pretty much undocumented, as far as I can tell, with people fishing around for parameters as I did at this page:

http://asnsblues.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html

This gets me halfway with &dirflg=r which defaults the directions to public transit, but I can't find a parameter reported anywhere for arrival time, probably because it's quite specific to public transit.

Comment: For those in the UK, transportapi.com are about as close as I've got to this, and offer an api that can return directions in html https://developer.transportapi.com/documentation/public-journey-planning

Comment: ...but transportapi only for London